# How to monitor a webpage for changes using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've searched for this a lot and for a long time, all I can find is online websites that will monitor websites for you but mostly require money to scan in short intervals. There might be software or browser extensions out there that also claim to do the job but I didn't have any success with them.

Since I'm learning JS, I thought there might be some way to do this myself.

Here's what I've thought of, comparing document.body before and after a change. So using Developer's Tools Console (F12), I tried this:

```
x=document.body
    <body style=​"background-color:​ rgb(21, 32, 43)​;​">​…​</body>​
r=document.createElement("p")
    <p>​</p>​
r.innerHTML="hi"
    "hi"
document.body.appendChild(r)
    <p>hi​</p>​
y=document.body
    <body style=​"background-color:​ rgb(21, 32, 43)​;​">​…​</body>​
x==y
    true
```

I don't understand why it reports "true", it should report false.

Why?

Any recommendation on how to get this done is very well appreciated.

---

new observation:

If `x=document.body`

then add a new `<p></p>` to `body`

and I do `x=x.innerHTML`

then do `y=document.body.innerHTML`

`x==y` will report true. (WHY?!)

BUT:

If `x=document.body` and I do `x=x.innerHTML`

then add a new `<p></p>` to `body`

then do `y=document.body.innerHTML`

`x==y` will report false.

Comment: Try to compare `x.textContent` and `y.textContent`. It is similar to `innerText` or `innerHTML` but has a couple [important differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText)

Comment: @powerc9000 That doesn't make sense, even `x.innerHTML==y.innerHTML` reports true

Comment: @Shayan Both variables are set to the body, so both are updated. Set `x` to `document.body.textContent` before modifying it

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but did you look at the MutationObserver? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @GammaGames It reports false! nice. ty. also comparing `x=document.body.innerHTML` `y=document.body.innerHTML` reports false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are comparing `x` and `y` in the example code you are checking if the body is equal to the body, they are the same element so they would be equal.

You would want to set `x` to the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText) or `innerHTML` of the body, then compare it in the same way after modification.

You can alternatively use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen for DOM changes as they happen, rather than at certain moments in time.

Comment: So I need to inject the `x=document.body`, reload the actual webpage I'm trying to monitor for changes, and somehow have the `x` variable` stored somewhere and then compare the new reloaded webpage with the old variable, any idea on how to do that? I honestly think it's not possible without an extension, unless I load the actual webpage inside another webpage using jQuery and then do all the above.

Comment: @Shayan You might be able to store it in a cookie or something, but an extension would probably be the best approach.

Comment: Is it possible to check for updates by retrieving the webpage's [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)? The ETag should change when the webpage's contents change.